# How to compare a String with a database table name?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database table in my android app. I want to compare database table name with a particular string.

**Here is my code**

```
 if(branchName == TABLE_NAME)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"table not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Here branchName is the `string.TABLE_NAME` is a static string and it is the name of the table.
Whenever I run this code, control goes to else part and shows the toast message.

Why? How can I fix that?

Comment: Post more code please

Answer (score 1):

for comparing two string you must use equal or equalsIgnoreCase ... ...

```
if (branchName.equalsIgnoreCase(TABLE_NAME) ){
// do sth
}
else{
Toast.makeText(this,"table not available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

try this way.